# is boto3 supported by ansible?

Tags: python, ansible, boto, boto3

so this is a pretty basic question but I couldn't find the answer in the ansible docs. Does Boto3 work with Ansible? I see that some of the docs on ansible have boto3 as a requirement, like these:

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_vpc_nacl_module.html
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_vpc_vgw_module.html

but then some don't, like these:

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_module.html
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_elb_module.html

or am I mis-reading it and some need boto and boto3?

Comment: Is this question specific to ec2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Boto3 is supported by Ansible "core" as modules' helpers (see [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/cb76200c7dd07f604b3bbf9f0d8b9fafde16b4b3/lib/ansible/module_utils/ec2.py#L43)).
And, as you mentioned, it is required by some newer modules, as `ec2_vpc_nacl`.

But older modules (like `ec2`) still require boto2 and will fail if it is not there, see [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/cb76200c7dd07f604b3bbf9f0d8b9fafde16b4b3/lib/ansible/modules/cloud/amazon/ec2.py#L609) and [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/cb76200c7dd07f604b3bbf9f0d8b9fafde16b4b3/lib/ansible/modules/cloud/amazon/ec2.py#L1592).